# CSV copy paste text issue

Tags: csv, delphi-xe5, adoconnection

I write a little tool for my workmate to import csv file to access.
There are a lot of data so I want to test it with few rows...
And the problem is when I copy few rows from the big CSV to a new CSV (COPY+PASTE) the program wont recognize the commas delimiter reads the full row... no enc-decoding, just simple text...

Header is this with +1 row
FOK;FOKNEV;SORSZAM;KDAT;BIZSZ;ELLENSZLA;ELLENSZLANEV;KTGH;KTGHNEV;SZOVEG;PÜ.SORSZAM;TARTOZIK;KOVETEL;HALM.EGYENLEG;IDOSZAKI EGYEN;KTGH / TK;FELOSZTAS;KTIP;KONSZ;KTGVIS
511199;EGYEB ANYAGOK;000000;2016.12.14.;PK/1029;381;PENZTAR HOLDING KOZPONT;7001;Vezérigazgatóság    ;80  Számla kifizetés;00000;5516,00;0,00;00000,00;5516,00;7001 T;5516,00;611;;;

Do You faced issue like this?

Here is the connection string for ADOconnection

```
  ConnectionString :=  'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source='+FilePath;    
  ConnectionString := ConnectionString+';Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Extended Properties=text';
  ConnectionString := ConnectionString+'Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=96;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;';
  ConnectionString := ConnectionString+'Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don'+FelVesszo+'t Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;FMT=Delimited'+';';
```

Comment: Pretty hard to understand this. Your text appears to use `;` as the delimiter rather than `,`. And `,` is the decimal point symbol it would seem. Anyway, I can't see a programming question here. Please visit the [help]. Once you've read the articles there in detail you should be able to realise what is wrong with the question.

Comment: My delimiter is "MT=Delimited;';" and if ill just copy and paste the text inside the file and save it, it cannot read recognize the delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved I modified the ODBC engine to force the separator

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text
Format=Delimited(;)
```